# Lable not appearing in UITable Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Have a problem where my Label is not appearing. But the slider does. Its one of these bizarre cases that seems there is no logical reason. Anybody able to make sense of this?

```
else if (indexPath.row == 4) 
{
    Filters *filters = [Filters sharedInstance];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, 80, 23);
    costSlider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    costSlider.maximumValue =  [[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 
 filters.maxCarRentalCost] floatValue];
    costSlider.minimumValue = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 
 filters.minCarRentalCost] floatValue];
    [costSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(costSliderChanged:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [costSlider setValue:[filters.maxCarCostPerDay floatValue] animated:YES ];
    costSlider.continuous = NO;
    costSlider.enabled = YES;
    costSlider.value = [filters.maxCarCostPerDay floatValue];
    costSlider.tag = 5;     
    [cell addSubview:costSlider];

    self.costLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    self.costLabel.text = @"what"; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cost per day: 
 %d", filters.maxCarCostPerDay ];        
    [self.costLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    self.costLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 75, 20);
    [self.costLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0]];
    [cell addSubview:self.costLabel];

}
```

Thanks
-Code

Comment: in addition to what Liam said, you should be adding stuff to cell's content view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted it does not look like you have `alloc`'d the label. Unless you are doing that elsewhere in the code, that is probably your issue